# How to create and store many statistics in SQL Server for Reporting Purposes

Tags: sql-server, reporting

I have a `C#` Program that creats `PowerPoint` reports filled with statistics of a chosen (by the project manager who operates with the tool) company (each one has a companyID).

The statistics are coming from a `SQL Server Database` but they are calculated over many different tables some based on surveys(like average working hours, department count, emplyee satisfaction). All together I will have around 40 values. These values I want to 1. use in my `C# Tool` for the creation and 2. store into a new Table ("`ReportX Values`") and provide it with a `timestamp`.

The point where I stuck is what is a efficient way of doing this?

All I can come up with is creating stored procedures for each statistic (around 40) with an imput paramter (`companyID`) and trigger these from `C#` each time a report got created. 
But this looks a bit infefficent. I am aware of `SSRS` and `SSIS` and I am not sure if there are better and more efficient ways to accomplish this. Anyone who can help me get a good stategy so I can start?

The tables are quite simple. Each survey has one table with companyId, personID and fields according to the questions in a survey like `question1, question2...` And I have a table with meta data with columns like e.g. companyID, PersonID, Department, CompanyName and some fields to cover possible hierachical structures.

A query could be:

```
Select sum(v1) from survey1 where companyid ='123'

Select avg(v1) from survey3 where v1 In (1,2) and companyid = 5
```

The goal would be to have a stable workflow and an easy interface from `c#` to the database.

Comment: Are these 40 tables well normalized? Editing the question to include some table definitions and typical queries would help a lot.

Comment: Being efficient means maximizing output for a given input. Often something else has to be relinquished in order to achieve that improvement. What do you want improved - run-time latency, design-time query writing, on-disk storage or ... ? What are you prepared to give up to achieve this?